# Should I store passphrase in jsp

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, passphrase

I need to generate a key with a passphrase in jsp using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 algorithms, CryptoJs library, then I use this key to encrypt the user login password and pass to server, and in the server, generate the key again and decrypt the user login password.

I know I should not pass the passphrase or key from client to server through http during login, but can I save the passphrase in login jsp page? if not, how can I use the passphrase to generate key in jsp?

even use a javascript variable to store the passphrase, the user can still use javascript debug mode to watch the passphrase variable value, so I think  no method to hidden the passphrase value in jsp, any method?

Or is the design of encrypt login password in client side using javascript has problem?

Answer (score 0):

No.Generate a one-way hash on the server for the user's input (using best practice, including a safe hashing algorithm and salting). Compare any future user input against that hash by generating a new hash with the user's input using the same algorithm, then compare the two hashes

Comment: then how to generate the key in jsp?

Comment: > Compare any future user input against that hash by generating the  
> hash with the same algorithm  
yes, then how to generate the same hash in jsp without storing the passphrase in jsp?

Comment: Edited: Generate a one-way hash on the server for the user's input (using best practice, including a safe hashing algorithm and salting). Compare any future user input against that hash by generating a new hash with the user's input using the same algorithm, then compare the two hashes.

Comment: @user1169587, you only store the hash. You must compare any future input from the user by generating a new hash and comparing the new hash against the original.

Comment: I still do not understand, in generating a new hash in jsp, I need to generate the key in jsp, then I need the passphrase in jsp...

Comment: `function hash(passphrase) { ... }` <- Write this function first. Then call this function for generation of the stored hash. Then call it again for comparison when the user submits a potentially valid passphrase.

Comment: hash(passphrase), but in jsp, user can use debug mode and watch the value of passphrase parameter?